# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefinedStack

Tags: node.js, react-native, azure-functions

[image: React-native-code]

[image: Postman]

[image: azure]

hello, im stuck with a problem. i made a azure function that deletes an item with the query of email, and id in the body. in postman i works perfect, so i know the function is works, but when i try calling it from the frontend it gives me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefinedStack: i dont know whats wrong, in console.log(id) it passes the correct id to the api, so it should be simmular to what postman does. im new in the game, so hope somebody can give me some pointers

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code like:

```
var obj = {"id": "your id"};
var config = { data: JSON.stringify(obj) };
await jsonServer.delete("/DeleteHours?email=" + info.current_user, config);
```

or

```
await jsonServer.delete("/DeleteHours?email=" + info.current_user, {
    "id":"your id"
});
```

The second option may not work, please have a try.

Comment: hmm, it did not work. its so strange becouse when i console.log(id) inside the body, it has the correct value, if i console.log(typeof id) it says string. and its the same object that comes from the database, it is not re-initialized again or used in the app. its just passed as parameter to the delete request